# Sending Order to Buy/Sell using the KrakenEx API in Python

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I have searched and tried to figure how to use the krakenex API from Kraken for my trading bot in order to send a Buy/Sell order:

So far I have tried this:

```
k = krakenex.API()

buy_vol = '0.02'
buy_price = get_purchasing_price(name)
k.query_private('AddOrder',
                    {'pair':name, #function is based in the name (i.e XETHZUSD - Ethereum)
                     'type':'buy',
                     'ordertype':'limit',
                     'leverage':'none',
                     'volume':buy_vol,
                     'price':buy_price
                     })
```

Where get_purchasing_price() is just taking the last recorded price for said Crypto and using it for the order.

Any help is gladly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you adding your API key and your secret key to your `API()` object ?
   In the documentation ([KrakenEx doc)](https://python3-krakenex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-krakenex), the API object should be set with these elements:

   `k = krakenex.API(key=your_key, secret=your_secret)`
2. In your data packet, you need to add the "**nonce**" parameter which is a counter that increase at each call to the api [Nonce Kraken API](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000906023-What-is-a-nonce-#1)
   You need to generate it before sending your order this way (multiple ways but this one works fine):

   ```py
   api_nonce = str(int(time.time()*1000))`

   k.query_private('AddOrder',
       {'nonce': api_nonce,
       'pair': pair_name,
       'type':'buy',
       'ordertype':'limit',
       'leverage':'none',
       'volume':buy_vol,
       'price':buy_price
   })
   ```